# Python Graphics Text

Tags: python

```
font=font.reader("Text",True,(R,G,B))
```

We are learning graphics in python and at one point came across text for graphics. I didn't understand the point of 'true' in the code though. What is the use of the word 'true' here? What would happen to my code if I wrote false?

Comment: Did you try it? What is the module being used here?

Comment: Try reading the documentation for the `font.reader` method.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what packages and modules you are using. So I can't exact answer for your question.

However, you can get the information of `reader` function by using `help`.
`help` function give the document for argument. This is example code for `sympy.sqrt` function

```
import sympy
help(sympy.sqrt)  ## it gives you a helpful information.
```

In your case, use the following code

```
help(font.reader)
```